# Compact manifolds and orientability

Tags: geometry, manifolds

I've a doubt about compact manifolds and orientability.

**I know that Compact Manifolds in $\mathbb{R^3}$ are orientable.**

My questions is:

The statement above is valid only for compact manifolds without boundary (in this case, closed manifolds)?

I'm asking this because I'd read that the Möbius-Strip with its boundary is a compact manifold.

Can someone explain me this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two notions here: manifold, and manifold-with-boundary. If you add the boundary circle to a Möbius strip, you get a manifold-with-boundary, which is not a manifold. The statement that all compact manifolds embedded in $\mathbb R^3$ is true. For $0$ and $1$-manifolds, it follows because all $0$ and $1$-manifolds are orientable. For surfaces it follows because any connected compact surface in $\mathbb R^3$ divides $\mathbb R^3$ into two pieces, which takes a little work to prove. (I like Alexander duality as a proof.) Then you can orient the surface by taking an outward-pointing normal vector at each point and using the right-hand rule to orient the tangent-plane at each point.

The statement is false for $\mathbb R^4$. You can embed the projective plane in $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: The (nice) proof you mention is perfectly fine for surfaces as 2-manifolds *without* boundary, but fails if you consider 2-manifolds *with* boundary. For example, both an "orientable strip" and a Möbius strip do not divide $\Bbb R^3$ in two distinct regions.

Comment: Ok, but is the mobius-strip a compact surface? And, the definition of compact surface is that which divides $\mathbb{R^3}$ in two pieces?

Comment: The user A.P. is right, the afirmation fail if we consider 2-manifolds WITH boundary, in this case, how is the assertion?

Comment: @A.P.:That is correct. A manifold by definition has no boundary. After manifolds-with-boundary are introduced, it is common practice to drop the "with boundary," but this is sloppy terminology.

Comment: @user64437: You are answering your own question. The statement is false for manifolds-with-boundary because you can embed the Möbius strip in $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 5):

It is pretty simple, actually. For some mathematicians the definition of *manifold* covers only those without boundary, while others distinguish between manifolds *with* or *without* boundary.

As you correctly observed, the Möbius strip is a non-orientable manifold with boundary which can be embedded in $\Bbb R^3$. Moreover it is a compact topological space, since for example it is a closed subspace of $\Bbb P^2_{\Bbb R}$.

Comment: So, the statement about compact manifolds is valid only with compact manifolds without boundary, in this case, closed manifolds?

Comment: Yes, although I would prefer to state it for compact 2-manifolds without boundary.